# Why the require_once is not working in following scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, require-once

I've following code of a function in a PHP file titled `sample.php` :

```
function deleteValue($value) {

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "jumbo";
  $dbname = "demo";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE value = '$value'";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $conn->close();     
    return true;
  } else {
    $conn->close();     
    return false;
  }  
}
```

Actually, in this file(`sample.php`) there are too many such functions which repeats the  following database connectivity code :

```
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "jumbo";
      $dbname = "demo";

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }
```

Then, I created one file titled `db.php` in the same folder and added the above code to it. Using `require_once('db.php');` at the beginning of file '`sample.php`'I included the file to the above code. Finally the code appeared as follows :

```
require_once('db.php');
function deleteValue($value) {

      $sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE value = '$value'";

      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $conn->close();     
        return true;
      } else {
        $conn->close();     
        return false;
      }  
    }
```

Now it's giving me 500 Internal Server error.

Even instead of including the file I tried by pasting the whole code from `db.php` at the beginning of file `sample.php` as follows but still I get 500 Internal Server Error.

```
$servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "jumbo";
  $dbname = "demo";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

function deleteValue($value) {

  $sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE value = '$value'";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $conn->close();     
    return true;
  } else {
    $conn->close();     
    return false;
  }  
}
```

Can someone please correct the mistake I'm making in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error? What does your error log say?

Comment: Can you access your page without this code? Internal Server Error seems more to me like a server configuration error -- arising from your htaccess file or apache's httpd.conf file -- rather than your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you that in **db_config.php** file you should use only database config and functions like this:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "jumbo";
$dbname = "jumbo_jet";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}
```

And in **common.php** use code like this:

```
require_once("db_config.php");

function deleteToken($receivedToken) {
  global $conn;
  $sql = "DELETE FROM user_login WHERE token = '$receivedToken'";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I hope it will work for you. If anything else then let me know.

Comment: Same is the thing I'm doing. If you look at my question closely you'll come to know that same thing I've done but got 500 Internal Server Error for it.

Comment: Then i think you have any other issue its not PHP script error. I am sorry!